# Pass mongodb aggregation variable to NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation

I am trying to use $gte in aggregation based on property from aggregation in Nodejs.

```
const twelveHours = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const pipeline = [
  { $addFields: { 
    twelveHoursBeforeStart: { $subtract: ['$startDate', twelveHours] } } // this works
  },
  { match: { 
    endDate: { $gte: new Date('$twelveHoursBeforeStart') }, // <- HERE pass a variable    
  },
]
```

I have tried different solutions like:

```
{ match: { 
  endDate: { $gte: '$twelveHoursBeforeStart' },
},
```

but non of them actually works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both the operations in `$match` stage,

- `$expr` expression match with aggregation `$gte` operator, first argument is `endDate` and second subtract condition

```
const twelveHours = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
           "$endDate",
           { $subtract: ["$startDate", twelveHours] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }  
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ESVgQLVrijp)

Comment: This isn't working on Node because it is compiled to:
```{ $expr: { $gte: ['$endDate', { $subtract: ['$startDate', twelveHours] }] } },```
Same result will have if compare to undefined. It expects a date object

Comment: is it string type or date type in your collection?

Comment: Isn't it same if we just do ```{ match: { endDate: { $gte: { $subtract: ["$startDate", twelveHours] } } } },```

Comment: no its not same, because `$subtract` is an aggregation expression operator and we are accessing internal `startDate` field as well so we can't use internal field in match condition, so that is why it requires to use `$expr` and there are 2 different syntax for simple `$gte` and expression `$gte`